# Pyspark: Unable to read a parquet file from SparkFiles

Tags: java, python, apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

After adding several files to `park using addFile and attempting to read a parquet file back using

```
parquet_dir = "/a/b/c.parquet"
spark.sparkContext.addFile(parquet_dir)

parquet_path = SparkFiles.get("c.parquet")
spark.read.parquet(f"file://{parquet_path}")
```

we got a java error where it's showing a java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException on a csv file

*answer = 'xro770', gateway_client = <py4j.java_gateway.GatewayClient object at 0x1273b6eb0>, target_id = 'o767', name = 'parquet'*

*py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o767.parquet.
E                   : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1) (10.196.190.115 executor driver): java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /Users/foorx/Developer/myproject/project-files/51e05c208b62b433293ef408fd1a3820.csv*

What could be causing pyspark to read a csv path when it should be reading a parquet path?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the bug was caused by deleting another local file that was added to spark. The driver will still try to reference the deleted local file and created runtime issues elsewhere.